# Programatically add a page in Wordpress

Tags: theme-development, wp-insert-post

I am trying to add a page to WordPress programatically. I am using this code:

```
 function add_media_page(){
if(!(is_page('My New Post'))){

// Create post object
  $my_post = array(
     'post_title' => 'My new Post',
     'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'post_author' => 1,
     'post_type' => ['page']
  );

// Insert the post into the database
  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_media_page' );
```

However when i use the last line in the array 'post_type' => ['page'] it causes the admin to crash and show a blank page. Does anyone know what's happening here

Comment: why are there square-brackets around it? You aren't referring to an object or an array, but passing a string as a value within the `$my_post`array - so it should be just `'page'`.

Comment: it's totally unhelpful when people downmark questions without bothering to mention why - it's supposed to be used if someone shows "no research effort" or if it's an "unclear or unuseful post"; not for if someone makes an error in the code, which I can only assume is why it's been downvoted. Otherwise why bother with a Q&A site in the first place since we're all so clever

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't downmarked it - that must've been someone else. I just added my comment as a quick partial answer, because I wasn't sure if my code-correction would be a complete answer. It is in my view a valid question - as I've had use of a similar method before - so I voted it back up to 0.

Comment: thanks - no i didnt necessarily think you did - but thanks for pointing out my error; that was it as it so happens.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

'post_type' => ['page'] is wrong; it should be 'post_type' => 'page'

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I think because your answer was the same as mine, but 4 days later. Now, a year after this, you unaccept my answer and accept your answer. Bit strange, don't you think?

Comment: I only did that because I don't believe that's what downvotes are for. The tick is MY choice, not yours!

Answer (score 2):

`'post_type' => ['page']` must be `'post_type' => 'page'`. Just look at the example here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post#Example

Answer (score 0):

Try this within your code in functions.php

```
global $user_ID;
$new_post = array(
'post_title' => 'My New Post',
'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'post_author' => $user_ID,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_category' => array(0)
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```